# Bison always returns: Error: syntax error on line 1

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I tried using only my scanner to see if there is an error there, but the scanner recognizes every token I want to generate well. I am still a beginner, so Im pretty lost on what to do differently.

This is my parser:

```
%{
#include "AST.h"  
#include "symbol_table.h"  

struct ast_node* root = NULL;  
struct symbol_table sym_table;  

void yyerror(const char* message);
%}

%union {
    char* string;
    int integer;
    struct ast_node* node;
}

%token <string> IDENTIFIER 
%token <integer> INT_LITERAL
%token PRINT INT VOID
%token IF ELSE MAIN FOR
%token LESS_EQUAL GREATER_EQUAL EQUAL ASSIGN LESS GREATER
%token PLUS MINUS MULT DIVIDE

%type <node> condition if_body else_body if_statements


%%

functions:
    function {printf("first function");}
    | functions function
    ;

function:
    returntype func_name '{' body '}'
    ;

returntype:
    INT
    | VOID 
    ;

func_name:
    IDENTIFIER '(' ')'
    ;

body:
    variable_declarations variable_assignments exec_statements print_statement
    ;

variable_declarations:
    variable_declaration
    | variable_declarations variable_declaration
    ;

variable_declaration:
    INT variable_names
    ;

variable_names:
    IDENTIFIER ';' 
    | IDENTIFIER ',' variable_names
    ;

variable_assignments:
    variable_assignments variable_assignment
    | variable_assignment
    ;

variable_assignment:
    IDENTIFIER '=' expression ';'
    ;

expression: 
    expression PLUS expression
    | expression MINUS expression
    | expression PLUS term
    | expression MINUS term
    | '(' expression ')'
    | term
    ;

term: 
    term MULT factor
    | term DIVIDE factor
    | factor
    ;

factor: 
    INT_LITERAL
    ;

exec_statements:
    exec_statements if_statements
    | exec_statements
    | if_statements
    ;

if_statements:
    IF '(' condition ')' '{' if_body '}'
    {
        struct ast_node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct ast_node));
        node->type = AST_IF;
        node->data.if_statement.condition = $3;
        node->data.if_statement.true_branch = $6;
        node->data.if_statement.false_branch = NULL;

        $$ = node;
    }
    | IF '(' condition ')' '{' if_body '}' ELSE '{' else_body '}'
    {
        struct ast_node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct ast_node));
        node->type = AST_IF;
        node->data.if_statement.condition = $3;
        node->data.if_statement.true_branch = $6;
        node->data.if_statement.false_branch = $10;

        $$ = node;
    }
    ;

condition:
    expression condition_op expression
    ;

condition_op:
    GREATER
    | LESS
    | LESS_EQUAL
    | GREATER_EQUAL
    | EQUAL
    ;

if_body:
    variable_assignments exec_statements
    | variable_assignments
    | exec_statements
    ;

else_body:
    variable_assignments exec_statements
    | variable_assignments
    | exec_statements
    ;
    


print_statement:
    PRINT '(' IDENTIFIER ')' ';'
    {
        printf("ok");
    }
    ;



%%

extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();
extern FILE *yyin;
extern yylineno;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    yyin = file;
    
    do {
        yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
}

void yyerror(const char* message) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s %d\n", message, yylineno);
}
```

and here my scanner:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include"parser.tab.h"

extern int yylineno;  
%}

%option noyywrap noyylineno

%%
"/*"                    {  }
"void"                  { return VOID; }
"int"                   { return INT; }
"if"                    { return IF; }
"for"                   {  }
"else"                  { return ELSE; }
"print"                 { return PRINT; }
"("                     { return ('('); }
")"                     { return (')'); }
","                     { return (',');  }
";"                     { return (';');  }
"="                     { return ASSIGN; }
"=="                    { return EQUAL; }
"<="                    {  }
"<"                     { return LESS;  }
">"                     {  return GREATER; }
">="                    {  return GREATER_EQUAL; }

"+"                     { return PLUS; }
"*"                     { return MULT;  }
"/"                     {  return DIVIDE; }
"-"                     {   return MINUS; }
"{"                     { return ('{'); }
"}"                     { return ('}'); }


[0-9]+                  { return INT_LITERAL; }
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*  { return IDENTIFIER;  }
[ \t\r\n]               ;  
.                       { printf("Unexpected character: %s\n", yytext); }
%%


int comment()
{
//function from a1
    char c, c1;

loop:
    while ((c = input()) != '*' && c != 0)
        putchar(c);

        putchar(c);
    if ((c1 = input()) != '/' && c != 0)
    {
        unput(c1);
        goto loop;
    } 

    if (c != 0)
        putchar(c1);
}
```

I guess there must be something wrong with my parser. Can somebody help me out what I should  try doing differently?

Comment: I recommend you start over, with something *much* more simple. For example a simple calculator that only recognizes addition and subtraction of single-digit numbers. Then add multi-digit numbers. Then add multiplication and division. Then add the ability to use multiple calculations as statements. Then add blocks. Then add functions. Perhaps even split it up in even more steps. Keep it simple, never try to create everything at once, always do it in many small and simple iterations that are easy to test and debug in isolation.